# Ruby - (JSON) with methods to block

Tags: ruby, json, block

I have a JSON with the following construct.

```
{
  "methods": [
    {
      "method": "method_name",
      "argument": "argument_value",
      "options_key": "options_value",
      "another_options_key": "options_value"
    },
    {
      "method": "method_name",
      "argument": "argument_value",
      "options_key": "options_value",
      "another_options_key": "options_value"
    }
  ]
}
```

This JSON gets parsed and the arguments are found with:

```
def parse_json(json)
    methods = JSON.parse(json, , :symbolize_names => true)
    methods.each do |options|
      pass_method(options)
    end
end

def pass_method(options)
  argument_names = self.class.instance_method(options[:method].to_sym).parameters.map(&:last)
  args = argument_names.map do |arg| 
    if arg == :options
      options
    else
      options[arg] || ''
    end
  end

  self.send(options[:method], *args)
end
```

Now I would like to pass blocks to those methods.
The JSON would look like:

```
{
  "methods": [
    {
      "method": "method_name",
      "argument": "argument_value",
      "options_key": "options_value",
      "another_options_key": "options_value",
      "block": [
        {
          "method": "method_name",
          "argument": "argument_value",
          "options_key": "options_value",
          "another_options_key": "options_value"
        },
        {
          "method": "method_name",
          "argument": "argument_value",
          "options_key": "options_value",
          "another_options_key": "options_value"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I make this work? So I can pass blocks to the methods and have sub-methods executed in the block?

Comment: Interesting. So to clarify, you want to be able to call methods on the current object based on the contents of some JSON object?

Could you clarify exactly what the equivalent Ruby code would be for the example JSON constructs you provided?

Comment: Also, is changing the structure of your JSON an option? Using the names of the method's parameters to decide what arguments to pass seems like a really strange way of doing things to me. (And your current approach is incompatible with keyword arguments in Ruby 2+)

Comment: The structure can be changed if it needs to be.

Comment: I just read http://robots.thoughtbot.com/ruby-2-keyword-arguments because I didn't knew keyword arguments. When using keyword-arguments, I still have to know how many and which arguments can be passed to the method to invoke it?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking, but to pass keyword arguments all you really have to know is the names of the arguments. Keyword arguments can be passed as a hash. E.g. `some_method("arg1", "arg2", {keyword_arg: "value"})`

Comment: I'm still not quite sure what you mean by "sub-methods executed in the block". Do you mean like `proc{|x| x.sub_method(arg1, arg2); x.other_sub_method(some_arg)}`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean  by sub-methods. (Didn't knew how to call them otherwise)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all I think your current approach of passing arguments based on the names of the method parameters is a bit strange. Instead, why not pass arguments as an array, similar to the form required by `Object#send`?

```
{
  "method": "push",
  "arguments": [
    1, "some_text", {"key": "value"}, ["array"]
  ]
}
```

This greatly simplifies the code, and makes it possible to pass keyword arguments using a hash.

As for how to pass blocks to methods, you can do that by constructing a [Proc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Proc.html) object, and passing that to the `send` method using the `&block` syntax:

```
method = :inspect
args = [1, "some_text", {"key": "value"}, ["array"]]
block = proc{|x| x.send(method, *args) }
some_object.send(:map!, &block)
```

Putting all these ideas together, we arrive at the following solution:

```
json = <<-JSON
{
  "methods": [
    {
      "method": "push",
      "arguments": [
        1, "some_text", {"key": "value"}, ["array"]
      ]
    },
    {
      "method": "delete",
      "arguments": ["some_text"]
    },
    {
      "method": "map!",
      "arguments": [],
      "block": [
        {
          "method": "to_s",
          "arguments": []
        } 
      ]
    }
  ]
}
JSON

def to_call_proc(method)
  method_name = method['method']    || ''
  arguments   = method['arguments'] || []
  block = to_multi_call_proc(method['block']) if method.has_key? 'block'

  if block
    proc{|x| x.public_send(method_name, *arguments, &block) }
  else
    proc{|x| x.public_send(method_name, *arguments) }
  end
end

def to_multi_call_proc(methods)
  call_procs = methods.map(&method(:to_call_proc))
  last_call_proc = call_procs.pop
  proc do |x|
    call_procs.each{|call_proc| call_proc.call(x)}
    last_call_proc.call(x) if last_call_proc
  end
end

def call_methods(receiver, methods)
  to_multi_call_proc(methods).call(receiver)
end

require 'json'

a = []
call_methods(a, JSON.parse(json)['methods'])
p a
```

Result:

```
["1", "{\"key\"=>\"value\"}", "[\"array\"]"]
```

Comment: The reason I used put the method name and arguments in the same array is to keep it as simple as possible, while still being very flexible.

Comment: @blablabla In my opinion that's actually quite a bit more complicated than just putting the arguments in an array. The way you had it, your code had to look up the names of the parameters used in each method. That way was pretty complex, and ignored a lot of edge cases like keyword arguments, rest parameters, and method_missing methods. Using an array greatly simplifies things by mirroring the way Ruby handles parameter passing.

Comment: You are right that the code is simpler, but to a user it isn't obvious why one parameter should be in the arguments array and another in an options array. That is why I want to make one array with all information for the method. (method name, arguments and options array), with blocks this would be the only exception I would have to make.

Comment: @blablabla From the API user's perspective, I still think this approach is simpler. For users familiar with Ruby, putting the arguments in an array makes sense, as that's how Ruby handles method calls anyway. (I'm not sure what you mean by options array. In your code, `options` was just a specially-named parameter that receives all the method data as its argument.) For users unfamiliar with Ruby, I would question whether "give me a list of methods to call" is the right level of abstraction to be using in your API in the first place.

Comment: Why, in to_multi_call_proc, do you pop the last proc?

Comment: @blablabla Because `Array#each` returns the entire array you are iterating over, and we need the returned `Proc` to return the return value of its last statement instead. Try my example without that part and see what happens.

Answer (score 3):

I'm confused about exactly what you're trying to do, but I think the below does it (pared down to just the block related code).

**DISCLAIMER: What you are doing looks either dangerous or redundant. If the JSON is coming from an untrusted source, you need to be *very* careful with whitelisting allowed methods so as not to allow arbitrary code execution. I would not trust myself to write this code. If the source is trusted, why not just `eval` plain Ruby code instead?**

```
class A
  def a
    puts "a start"
    yield
    puts "a end"
  end

  def b; puts "b" end
  def c; puts "c"; yield end
  def d; puts "d" end

  def call(spec)
    spec.each do |m|
      # Use #fetch because this is required
      method_name = m.fetch(:method)
      block_spec  = m[:block]

      block = if block_spec
        ->(*args) {
          # Recursively evaluate, meaning that block specs can themselves
          # contain blocks!
          call(block_spec)
        }
      else
        # Using a default empty block is easier than not providing one and
        # using conditionals to workaround it.
        Proc.new{}
      end

      # WARNING: This is unsafe! If spec does not come a trusted source, this
      # allows arbitrary code execution which is really bad.
      send(method_name, &block)
    end
  end
end

spec = {
  methods: [
    {
      method: "a",
      block: [{
        method: "b"
      }, {
        method: "c",
        block: [{method: "d"}]
      }]
    }
  ]
}

A.new.call(spec[:methods])
```

Output:

```
a start
b
c
d
a end
```

Comment: +100 to the disclaimer. I have a bad feeling about this Question :-/

Comment: Good point in the disclaimer. The JSON is coming from the client in a rails application. Is validating the method names with a list of allowed methods enough to overcome this?

Comment: @blablabla If you're passing this untrusted client-side code, a whitelist is a must. Otherwise I could pass `{"methods":["method":"instance_eval", "arguments":["Kernel.exec 'rm -rf /'"]]}` and bam! There goes your server.

Even with a whitelist though, you still need to be careful that the methods you have on that whitelist are sanitizing user input appropriately, and don't have any vulnerabilities that a malicious client could exploit by passing unexpected arguments to the method.

Comment: @blablabla I'd suggest asking another question about your overall goal, there might be a more secure way of achieving it.

Comment: The reason is I want to create a simple prawn-pdf editor. I don't want to wrap all methods of prawn, so I thought if I just made it so the JSON can be interpreted into prawn methods. The reason I chose to use JSON is so I could easily save the JSON string to a database and in the future create a javascript front-end editor.